# Почему не выполняется SQL запрос в PreparedStatement в Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, запрос, preparedstatement

Есть такой код:

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ResultSet result = null;

String query =
"SELECT passenger_id, name, surname, dateOfBirth FROM passengers " + 
"  WHERE passenger_id IN " +
"    (SELECT passenger_id FROM tickets " +
"      WHERE bus_id=?)";

statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setInt(1, bus.getBusId());
result = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Запрос должен вернуть таблицу, и он работает, если выполнять из консоли MySQL.
Однако при попытке выполнить программу возникает следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: а где конкретно ошибка возникает, на prepare или не execute?

Comment: @rjhdby при вызове executeQuery()

Comment: @rjhdby Если убрать знак ? и statement.setInt(), то все работает, проблема в том, что ? распознается как некорректный синтаксис, а не как место, в которое нужно подставить int...

Comment: поменяйте на `result = statement.executeQuery();`

Comment: @rjhdby Как я сам не заметил... Спасибо! :D